# Shared neutral betwen 120v AC line and 82v ac output of triac phase dimmer?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, mains, triac, dimmer

I'm building a power supply for an old photographic enlarger (LPL/Saunders 4500ii aka 7451).

The enlarger has a jones connector with four pins for ground, a fan (120v ac), and a 200W bulb (82v ac RMS), and a shared neutral between the fan and bulb.

I've built a working prototype using [this triac phase dimmer module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CT8F9KX) and an arduino ATTiny85 to send an appropriate PWM signal that results in about 82vac RMS with a 200W load.  I've tested it successfully with an old overhead projector bulb that is also 82v 200W.

My plan is to wire the output jones connector's ground, neutral, and fan lines straight to the ac input equivalents.  The output bulb line goes to the triac dimmer module's hot line output (through a relay of course so my darkroom timer can control it).

I assume I also need to wire the triac dimmer's neutral out into the output neutral.  **But that means the triac module's input and output neutral are directly connected, and both to the ac line neutral and load neutrals as well.  Is that a bad idea?**

Edit:  here is a simplified diagram of what I'm considering:
[image: diagram]

Comment: I think this setup should also have some form of reverse polarity protection, in case the hot line winds up going through that neutral from a mis-wired plug, but that's a second project.

Comment: No such thing as reverse polarity on AC. The dimmer knows no difference. I’d suggest you show a drawing of what you’re proposing.

Comment: @Kartman there certainly is polarity on AC.  One active conductor is chosen and bonded to safety ground/protective earth.  That wire is called "Neutral" henceforth: light blue or white.  When equipment exposes one active conductor moreso than the other, they must use neutral for that one.  An example is the "shell" of an Edison screw-in socket. That's called polarization/polarity, e.g. the taller blade on American sockets or the forced orientation on AU and UK sockets.

Comment: @Kartman  Normally, yes, I'd agree.  But here, having reversed polarity of the incoming AC would mean that both sides of the triac module are getting line voltage, and it's also going to the poor enlarger bulb.